# Adding animation on screen focus React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I want to run my animations from react-native-reanimated everytime my screen is focused. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly, but in most cases you can use the useIsFocused hook from react navigation.

like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

function YourScreenScreen() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

   React.useEffect(() => {
    
   //put whatever you want here when the screen is focused

  }, [isFocused]);

  return <>......</>;
}
```

more reference [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/)
Hope this answers your question, Gl!